# stuuby is not returning response for my request with quer param containing %

Tags: regex, npm, stub

I am using stubby for my application and I have to send the string `DW3e62y6%2FvCAE%2Fhx%2F3z4eRuVG%2FIy0XdvxUDBNsfCRn2c8AHw60L%2F3A%3D%3D` for query param of my request. But stubby is not returning response with this query param having `%`

`- request:
    url: ^/myendpoint.php$
    method: POST
    query:
      codeValue: "DW3e62y6%2FvCAE%2Fhx%2F3z4eRuVG%2FIy0XdvxUDBNsfCRn2c8AHw60L%2F3A%3D%3D"
  response:
    status: 200`

If I remove the query param from this code, the response is 200. But I need this query param too. Is there any way to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try *proxy_pass* [nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html).

Comment: i am using this for writing unit tests. There is no nginx used

Comment: I've had similar problem in Kubernetes Ingress. There was no option to rewrite without encoding URL.